# SQL select with GROUP BY and COUNT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have three tables to manage purchases from my online shop:

- **Products:**  with columns ID, Name, Price
- **Customers:**  with columns ID, Name
- **Purchases:** with columns ProductID, CustomerID, PurchaseDate

Now, how would I go about retrieving products purchased by more than `N` distinct customers?

I've tried the following on SQL Server 2019 Trial Edition but I'm getting a syntax error on COUNT.

```
SELECT ProductID, CustomerID, COUNT(*) as C    
FROM Purchases    
GROUP BY ProductID, CustomerID    
HAVING C > 100    
ORDER BY C DESC
```

Better still, how would I go about retrieving products purchased by more than `N` distinct customers over a 30-day period?

Thanks for any help and/or pointers.

Comment: Your current schema doesn't support this, you are not storing timestamps of purchases.
In present scenario there is no way to filter purchases on data range.

Comment: Please post the exact error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current query, you are just counting how often each customer bought each product, because you are grouping by the combination of `productid` and `customerid`. Furthermore you cannot reference to the column alias for the count in the `HAVING` or `ORDER BY` clause

Try this

```sql
declare @purchasedatelower datetime = dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
declare @purchasedateupper datetime = getdate()
declare @distinctcustomers int = 100

select productid, count(distinct customerid) as customercount
from purchases
where purchasedate between @purchasedatelower and @purchasedateupper
group by productid
having count (distinct customerid) >= @distinctcustomers
order by count(distinct customerid) desc
```

This will return all products, which have been bought by at least 100 distinct customers, in the last 30 days, together with the distinct number of customers.

Comment: This does the trick. And many thanks for your explanation!

Comment: I have already. And I'm getting the message "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @KeineUrsache you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark. What you can't do (yet) is upvote the answer by clicking on the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to order them by `COUNT()`

```
SELECT ProductID, CustomerID

FROM Purchases

GROUP BY ProductID, CustomerID

HAVING COUNT(*) > 100

ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: It's better but I'm also getting items purchased multiple times by just one single customer.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, how would I go about retrieving products purchased by more than N distinct customers?

You would use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT ProductID, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) as num_customers   
FROM Purchases    
GROUP BY ProductID    
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) > 100    
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) DESC;
```

If you have a particular period in mind, then add a `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Popularity int = 1
DECLARE @MonthsAgo int = 1

SELECT p.ProductId, p.ProductName, pc.CustomersDistinct
FROM (
    -- Sub-query to compute the aggregate.
    -- Count the number of distinct customers that purchased each product.
    SELECT ProductId, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) AS CustomersDistinct
    FROM Purchases
    WHERE PurchaseDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -@MonthsAgo, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    GROUP BY ProductId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) > @Popularity
) AS pc
    -- Now do JOINs to look up helpful values for the final SELECT list.
    INNER JOIN Products p ON pc.ProductId = p.ProductId
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```